# Suggested edit notification wrong

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The suggested edit notification has been consistently wrong (in an inconsistent way) for a few weeks now. No amount of refreshing and cache-deletion seems to fix it.

[image: wrong screenshot]

It's always off, but the amount by which it's wrong varies.

Is it just me?

---

This stopped happening for a while, then started again..

Comment: This is by design. See this post at Meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233535/224428.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy paste from [meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233536) for closure.

> It won't, at least not always. The review indicator in the top-bar is not calculated on a per-user basis, but on a per-site basis. The counts in the review queue itself are calculated on a per-user basis. The top-bar indicator also won't always be accurate (and it's cached), which is why the tooltip has a `~` to indicate it's an approximate value.
>
> There are several things that could cause an item to not show up for you in review, but still show up in the total per-site count. It could be that you've already reviewed the item and it's still waiting to be completed, you could have skipped it, or you could have previously taken action on the post in question that prevents you from being able to review it.