# Why do I have reviews indicated in the top bar, and nothing when I'm clicking on it?

Tags: discussion

An image to show what I mean (surrounded in green):

[image]

Is there a reason for that?

Comment: This is a known issue: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233535/238438

Comment: Also related: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/955/599